# Why can't I use this Template factorial function on a non-constant expression?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to familiarize myself with Template-Metaprogramming

Consider the following code, which uses the basic introductory Factorial 
template function found in many template tutorials online.

```
#include <iostream>

  template <int N> struct Factorial {
       static const int result = N * Factorial<N-1>::result;

  };

  template <> struct Factorial<0> {
       static const int result = 1;

  };

  int main() {

       int tmp;
       std::cin >> tmp;
       static const int tmpc = tmp;
       std::cout << Factorial<tmpc>::result << "\n";
       return 0;

  }
```

The example works perfectly if I set `tmpc=10` say, i.e. to be a compile-time constant. But if tmpc = tmp then, I get the compile error

```
templates.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
templates.cpp:30:29: error: the value of ‘tmpc’ is not usable in a constant expression
      std::cout << Factorial<tmpc>::result << "\n";
                             ^~~~
templates.cpp:29:23: note: ‘tmpc’ was not initialized with a constant expression
      static const int tmpc = tmp;
                       ^~~~
templates.cpp:30:33: error: the value of ‘tmpc’ is not usable in a constant expression
      std::cout << Factorial<tmpc>::result << "\n";
                                 ^
templates.cpp:29:23: note: ‘tmpc’ was not initialized with a constant expression
      static const int tmpc = tmp;
                       ^~~~
templates.cpp:30:33: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
      std::cout << Factorial<tmpc>::result << "\n";
```

Does this mean, I can use Templated functions only on *compile-time* constant expressions?!!!

Where am I going wrong in my understanding?

Comment: Because templates are compile time construct?

Comment: Yes, this is the essence of template metaprogramming - it works with input knowing at compile time. This is why it is called **meta** programming - you instruct a compiler to create a program, as opposed to *programming* when you instruct compiler to create an executable (loosely speaking).

Comment: @SergeyA So the only way to calculate the factorial of a function at run-time (where the user supplies the value) is to resort to standard C++?

Comment: Template meta programming in C++ **is** standard in the sense of ISO. I would hesitate to add any adjective ("standard", "usual", "old", etc.) to distinguish between compile- and runtime C++.

Comment: @smilingbuddha, well, templates are standard C++, so it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: Ok sorry for the snafu. By 'standard' I really mean the non-meta programming part of C++.

Comment: look at the standard library, it has templates everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean, I can use Templated functions only on compile-time
>   constant expressions?!!!

Be careful with terminology. A template function can use runtime values, but a *metafunction* cannot, since it is (by definition) evaluated at compile time.

A function template is a little more ordinary:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T arg) { /*...*/ }
```

Calling f() will cause a different instantiation of f() for each unique type used, but it's still a runtime function taking a runtime value.

With a metafunction, the argument itself is the template parameter, and template parameters cannot be runtime values.

Answer (score 0):

> I can use Templated functions only on compile-time constant expressions?

Yes. Templates are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Better suited for the comment.

Comment: @SergeyA I can't decide if I agree with you. I can't think of what the question should be closed as, and this really is an answer to the question. If the question should be closed, I agree that it should be a comment.